# extconf.rb failed (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to ruby and rails. I've set up ruby 2 on rails 4 successfully (On windows 7). I cloned a ruby on rails based git project (thingspeak - https://github.com/iobridge/thingspeak/blob/master/README.textile). Using the command line I went into the project directory and ran "bundle install". A few bundles got downloaded and installed and then I got the following error -

```
::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    c:/row/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
checking for clockid_t in time.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... no
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
getaddrinfo required
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/row/Ruby200/bin/ruby
        --with-rtlib
        --without-rtlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib

Gem files will remain installed in c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kgio-
2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kgio-2.8.1/ext/kgio/ge
m_make.out
An error occurred while installing kgio (2.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any ideas on what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: Please, provide the full trace.

Comment: One of the possible reason you are missing some library that need to pre-install before bundle install, otherwise the gem cannot be compiled successfully.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you're doing that on Windows - an environment that's not really friendly to rails.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to paste the last part of the stack trace. U can now see the full stackstrace.

Answer (score 0):

The `kgio` gem which fails to compile here does not work on Windows. It *could* work if you comment the respective line in the `Gemfile` but could fail in various other places.

Generally, the Rails app you want to install doesn't seem to be tested on Windows at all, so you might instead want to use a better supported OS to install it. The README mentions Ubuntu here.